# Cancel All Running Task

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, task

I can not stop the created task The following code will not happen

```
ts?.Cancel();
```

and this is how i run task

```
ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
await ((ViewModel)DataContext).loadTitles(progressTitle, ts.Token, prg);
```

and in viewmodel

```
public async Task loadTitles(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken ct, ProgressBar prg)
        {
             if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            foreach (var line in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(GlobalData.Config.DataPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                mprogress += 1;
                progress.Report((mprogress * 100 / totalFiles));
                var item = ShellFile.FromFilePath(line);

                ArtistNames.Add(new ArtistData
                {
                    Name = item.Properties.System.Title.Value,
                    Tag = line
                });
                await Task.Delay(5);
            }
        }

        }
```

I've written similar to the same function for four other functions, and the tasks are stopped well, but this one does not work.

Comment: I think we'd need to see more of the code in `loadTitles` to diagnose that. All I see right now is that the function won't execute if the token has already been cancelled when the function is entered.

Comment: You don't throw OperationCanceledException. I think you missed `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`

Comment: @DmitryStepanov i dont need to throw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop your tasks because at the very begininnig of `loadTitle` method you check whether the cancellation was requested. But it wasn't and can't be because you immediately step into a `foreach` loop. You need to check it inside of a a loop:

```
public async Task loadTitles(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken ct, ProgressBar prg)
{
    foreach (var line in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(GlobalData.Config.DataPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }

        // ... the rest of your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing listening to `CancellationToken` inside your method, except the first line.

If you want to implement graceful cancellation,  test token inside loop and pass it to `Task.Delay`.

Note, that if `loadTitles` is being called from UI thread, it mostly runs in the same UI thread, because there's nothing async here except `Task.Delay`, which preserves caller context and continues async method in UI thread. To avoid this behavior you need to call `ConfigureAwait(false)` after `Task.Delay`.